# Running Python Scripts on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, dependencies

I have a set of scrapers written in python that I'm trying to host on Heroku. I've pushed the repo to heroku, and it will begin to run, but quits with an error I never encountered in my local environment.

when I call `p = Legislator(name=name, district=district)` where both name and district are strings, I get `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`

both Legislator and Person are included in packages my script is dependent on, both of which are specified in `requirements.txt`
could this have something to do with virtualenv?

here is the constructor for Legislator:

```
    def __init__(self, name, post_id, party=None, chamber=None, **kwargs):
       super(Legislator, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
       self.post_id = post_id
       self.party = party
       self.chamber = chamber
       self._contact_details = []
```

and the constructor for Person

```
   def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
       super(Person, self).__init__()
       self.name = name
       self.biography = None
       self.summary = None
       self.birth_date = None
       self.death_date = None
       self.image = None
       self.gender = None
       self.links = []
       self.other_names = []
       self.extras = {}
       self._related = []
       self.contact_details = []

       for k, v in kwargs.items():
           setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with python 3 inheritance, so apologies if this is a ignorant question, but why are you calling `super(Person, self).__init__()` inside the constructor for Person?  It looks like you're trying to make Person inherit from Person.  And if there is a good reason to do that, shouldn't it be `super(Person, self).__init__(name)`?

Comment: that confuses me a bit too to be honest, that part isn't my code, its from the package I'm using. Person comes from https://github.com/opencivicdata/larvae/blob/master/larvae/person.py and Legislator comes from https://github.com/opencivicdata/pupa/blob/master/pupa/scrape/helpers.py

Comment: Waitaminute - if Legislator takes arguments `self, name, post_id, party=None, chamber=None, **kwargs`, and you gave it `<Legislator instance>, name=name, district=district`, then you haven't given it a `post_id` argument, have you?  Isn't that the 3rd missing argument?  I'm not sure how you managed to avoid this error in your local environment...

Comment: aha! you're right! turns out post_id was added two days ago and I didn't update the dependencies on my local environment. Thank you!!

Comment: No prob - I missed it the first time around :)

Comment: @Brionius Hey great work and great answer :) You should take your comment and post it as an actual answer to this question. Then you can get the credit for solving it (I will upvote you!), and the answer can be marked as Accepted. This will help show the problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legislator takes arguments:

`self`, `name`, `post_id`, `party=None`, `chamber=None`, and `**kwargs`

and you gave it

`<Legislator instance>`, `name=name`, and `district=district`,

then you haven't given it a `post_id` argument - that's the 3rd missing argument.